# ECHO Variable include newline

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following code:

```
<p><?php echo $item['desc']; ?></p>
```

The code pulls the following from the database:

```
Point 1
Point 2 
Point 3
```

and displays it as: Point 1 Point 2 Point 3,

What do I need to do to get the new lines included, I've tried adding /n or 
 tags into to the DB reference however it is not making any difference.

Comment: What is $item..??array ..??

Comment: do you want to add newline after each point x (item['desc'])?

Comment: it should be \n, not /n - just a correction, not that it really matters anyway since you should use another approach pointed out in the answers.

Answer (score 5):

This should work

```
<p><?php echo nl2br($item['desc']); ?></p>
```

Otherwise:-

```
echo nl2br(str_replace(' ',"\n", $item['desc']));
```

Comment: @vascowhite, probably the first one worked. Because on the second one you will insert newlines between `Point` and the number, so there will be 6 lines instead of 3. If the first one worked, then my answer is wrong. :)

Comment: @enenen Yes, well spotted, I'd missed that too :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the newlines are being printed, but you need them to be `<br>` tags, so they will appear as newlines on the webpage? You can use the function [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for that:

```
<p><?php echo nl2br($item['desc']); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

The newline is included. It's just not displayed in the browser, because the HTML standard says so. If you want it displayed in the browser, change newline to `<br>` tags, e.g. using [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo str_replace(' ',"\n", $item['desc']);
```

Answer (score 0):

\n won't work because the string you print has to be processed by the browser in html.
Use `<br>` tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
echo str_replace(' ',"<br>", $item['desc']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand exactly what you want but probably it's something like this:

```
$string = "Point 1 Point 2 Point 3";

$string = preg_replace("/(point \d+ )/i", "\$1\r\n", $string);

echo $string
```

Output:

```
Point 1 
Point 2 
Point 3
```

**Note:** Use only `nl2br` (see other answers) if the new lines are already in the string but just not displayed.

Comment: No need for regex here, it is quite expensive. `nl2br()` is the tool of choice for exactly this scenario.

Comment: If the new lines are in the string already, then yes. But I'm not sure for this when reading OP's question.

Comment: No, I wasn't sure either, I guess they were as my first option worked.

Answer (score 0):

if your code in one line like TEST TEST TEST you can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function :

```
echo preg_replace("{[ ]+}","<br/>",$items['desc']);
```

if your string like this TEST 1 TEST 2 ... and your goal is :
TEST 1
TEST 2
... so on..
you can use this pattern:

```
$t =  preg_match_all("{[\w]+[ ]?[0-9]+}",$items['desc'],$m);
foreach ($m[0] as $val) { echo $val."<br/>"; }
```